# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server (with close connection and AUTO CLOSE false)

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core

I run some SQL queries on Azure from a .NET Core 2.2 console application, using Dapper in this way:

```
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_appSettings.ConnectionStrings))
    db.Execute("delete from MyTable where Id=@id", new { id = myObject.Id });
```

Sometimes (but very few time during the day) I get this error:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 2827   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 570   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 443
> at ProjectQueue.Engine.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in C:\Users\userX\source\repos\myProject\ProjectQueue\Engine.cs:line 75

I searched in SO, and some tips are regard setting to false AUTO CLOSE on SQL (which I already have):

[image]

What can it be? How can investigate more and resolve the problem?

Comment: Assuming you've already checked for obvious things like network dropouts on wifi etc, I have a question, which is going to sound a bit crazy at first: do you have any network security appliances between the client and SQL?

Comment: @allmhuran since it happens "sometimes", i dubt there's some security appliances between the client and SQL, right?

Comment: Right? I knew it would sound crazy. The reason why I ask is this: We had a similar issue a couple of years ago. After months of tearing my hair out, I eventually discovered that there was a security appliance that was killing certain network requests based on packet size. I eventually found that when the query text was a particular length, the query would consistently fail with a transport error. Adding or subtracting a single character would fix it. The only problem is I can't find my records on the exact details! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure SQL is known for having "transient errors" occasionally when connecting or issuing commands. Of course there could be other causes also for your specific error (network devices issues, hardware issues), but since they only happen occasionally and are not reproducible, the transient error handling solutions still apply.

In Azure, there can be a number of causes for these transient issues, often related to some auto-scaling or an infrastructure issue that is being mitigated behind the scenes by Azure engineers or by some Azure auto-healing, for which you will normally not have any visibility.

The main solution and the one recommended strongly by Microsoft is to implement retry handling to handle these "transient" issues.  You could use a .NET library like Polly (https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), or build your own with a while loop (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/step-4-connect-resiliently-sql-ado-net?view=sql-server-ver15#step-2b-copy-and-paste-sample-code).  They often recommend a  retry back-off strategy that includes retrying quickly for the first retry, and if it keeps failing, then increase your retry intervals on subsequent retries.

Make sure you log the exceptions when retrying, so that you can determine if the issue becomes more persistent.

More info about Azure SQL transient errors:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-connectivity-issues

And transient error handling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/transient-faults

Comment: The error is repeated even with retries.

Comment: This is easy to reproduce. Disable network card and enable. After that, the service will never connect to the database.